# WSO2 Carbon Identity Server - Build and run

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I've modified a .jsp file in the `org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.ui` package, in order to customize the server for my purposes.

The problem is that when I build the project with Eclipse, the **build is successful**, but I don't understand how I can actually run the compiled code. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you build the project with maven, in the target directory you will find the jar (OSGi bundle). In your IS Server under /repository/component/patches, create a new directory something similar to "patch0100". Copy the jar inside this "patch0100" directory and restart the IS server.

The number in the patch directory (0100 in this case) is important. If you put the same jar to a patch directory with a higher number, say pactch0200, that particular jar with override the earlier one. That's how patching works in WSO2 Carobon Server, which is the platform on which the products are built.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The patching system works great. The problem now is that the modifications I did on the .jsp, don't show up when I run the server. I checked in the patch jar and the .jsp file is in it and with the updated code. I simply don't understand why it doesn't work.
In particular, the file is basic-policy-editor.jsp.